# Helm: search within buffer feature?

Tags: helm, search

A pretty basic Helm question.  What is the Helm window/command/feature that lets us search for text (preferably using `regexp`) within any type of buffer (i.e., including read-only such as `w3m`)?

In other words, I'm looking for Helm's equivalent of Emacs' native commands for `isearch-forward` (`C-s`) / `isearch-backward` (`C-r`).

To illustrate: after invoking one of the native `isearch` commands (`C-s` or `C-r`), we can exit search mode in one of two ways:

1. we can exit and return to original point (via `C-g`), or
2. we can exit and continue browsing buffer from current point i.e., from the
   currently-matched text (via `RET` among others).

I'm looking for the second of these two options.

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

- `helm-regexp`: this is the closest thing to what I'm looking for but it only performs the equivalent of `C-s`/`C-r` + `C-g` (i.e., it takes us back to the original point; no option for terminating the search and continuing to browse the buffer from the currently matched point).
- `helm-do-grep`: it seems like this is only for searching for text within files (i.e., doesn't work on w3m)
- `helm-buffer-run-grep` / `-zgrep`: running this command/function results in an error message in the mini-buffer: `Running helm command outside of context`
- when `helm-mode` is enabled, invoking `C-s` or `C-r` brings up Emacs' native `isearch` feature (it isn't replaced by Helm's interface).  (maybe there's a setting we can change so Helm can take over this command?  i.e., similar to how Helm takes over the native command for `write-file` (`C-x C-w`) which can be used to rename a file in an open buffer.  just brainstorming.)

Comment: You want `helm-occur` with `follow-mode` enabled.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use helm-occur as a tool that comes with the basic helm module for this.
But to me, one of the best helm based tools for buffer searching is Shingo Fukuyama's [helm-swoop](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop). You can get it from github and via MELPA. It has your required functionality of being able to drop your point at the position of the match (which can be a regexp). But you can also use C-g to have the cursor back where you started.

On the helm-swoop github page you'll find a whole bunch of other useful functions that this package offers (including multi-buffer searches by helm-multi-swoop and the ability of editing the lines of the results, so that the changes are applied to the underlying buffer).

Comment: I agree. `helm-swoop` is really an improved version of `helm-occur`.

Comment: So, I'm obv a bit late to this front.  I tried `helm-swoop`...and I'm never going back!  Thanks

Comment: Good lord, helm-swoop is something not from this world.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `helm-occur` to see all of the lines that contain matches for your search pattern.  You can use `C-n` and `C-p` to navigate the list, and then press `RET` to close the Helm buffer and jump your cursor to the matching line.

I like to enable `helm-follow-mode` when I use `helm-occur` so that the source window always shows the context of currently-selected match.  You can enable follow-mode automatically as follows:

```
(require 'helm-config)

(defvar my-helm-follow-sources ()
  "List of sources for which helm-follow-mode should be enabled")

;; Use helm-follow-mode for the following sources:
(add-to-list 'my-helm-follow-sources 'helm-source-occur)

(defun my-helm-set-follow ()
  "Enable helm-follow-mode for the sources specified in the list
variable `my-helm-follow-sources'. This function is meant to
be run during `helm-initialize' and should be added to the hook
`helm-before-initialize-hook'."
  (mapc (lambda (source)
          (when (memq source my-helm-follow-sources)
            (helm-attrset 'follow 1 (symbol-value source))))
        helm-sources))

;; Add hook to enable helm-follow mode for specified helm 
(add-hook 'helm-before-initialize-hook 'my-helm-set-follow)
```